# Trouble finding the IP adress

Tags: ip, port-forwarding

I use my android device
to connect to my desktop.

for some reasons I need to know my 
IP address. so I checked with
Opera mini, uc browser and IPtools.
and all shows a different IP address.
and I'm confused now.
can anyone help me to chose the correct 
one . Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which address? Internal/External? Have you done any research on this?

Comment: @Bort its External IP address. yes. everywhere it states to google "What is my ip" and i end up getting different IP addresses

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a few examples of IP addresses that you are seeing, as well as where exactly you are getting them from? Also, while you are editing, please state your ultimate goal in the question itself; comments are ephemeral and subject to deletion, but questions and answers remain on the site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want know the public IP just Google in your Browser "[What's my IP](https://www.google.co.in/#newwindow=1&q=whats+my+ip)" or Go to the [Link](http://whatsmyip.net/) . If you want to know Private IP you can get it by Settings -> About -> Status -> IP adddress there must be an IP like 192.168.1.X which is your local IP(IPV4).
Or

You can find your Public IP on your router too.

Comment: As I said. I tried googling "What is my ip " with different browsers . And ended up getting different Ip addresses in each browsers

Comment: I think you're stuck up with dynamic IP ask your ISP for Static Public IP, they will charge some little extra amount to allot a Unique IP to you

Comment: And I dont have a router. I use my android mobile

Comment: Mobile IP's will change every time you change cell towers.